# Debugging in Pharo 5 headless mode

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm running pharo 5 (seaside) in headless mode, with RFB:

./pharo -vm-display-null -vm-sound-null /app/pharo5/Pharo5.0.image --no-quit

Locally works well (Ubuntu 14 with XFCE).

In DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 14 without GUI) it works until the debugger is activated: then it closes.
I can connect via VNC with no problem, but when I execute a Halt or an error it triggers the debugger, it leaves ... some clue of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case where remote debugging might be a reasonable approach. This project, [PharmIDE](http://dionisiydk.blogspot.fr/2017/01/pharmide-pharo-remote-ide-to-develop.html), (previously name, "Remote Debugging", currently named "TelePharo") purports to provide debugging of remote images. There is a repository for it [on Github](https://github.com/dionisiydk/TelePharo) under the current name.

*[Disclaimer, I have not used it.]